# "embedly" not working in a wordpress HTML widget

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, embed, embedly

I manage a site for my father who is doing a from Canada to key west. He got some press from ABC news and I am tryign to embed the actual video on our site not just a link to the ABC page. Embedly says that it can do it and even creates a great lookign iframe code. One the website however it is not showing the video and just the links.

Here is the code it gave me to use.

```html
<blockquote class="embedly-card" data-card-key="9a1d9b138e404b67ba0a852c5be91478" data-card-theme="dark" data-card-align="left"><h4><a href="http://www.wcti12.com/news/Man-runs-from-Canada-to-Florida-for-multiple-sclerosis/35489206">Man runs from Canada to Florida for multiple sclerosis</a></h4><p>A man from Pennsylvania is running from Canada to Key West to raise awareness for multiple sclerosis. He was in Carteret County on Friday.</p></blockquote>
<script async src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

It is put in a WordPress text widget on a genesis theme homepage.   (http://canadatokeywestcoastalrun.org/) in the found Stephen section

Any help to get this working?

Comment: Looks like you got it working?

Comment: No not yet. It seems to work on Mobile but not on desktop. I have check IE FF Chrome and no dice. On my android it shows. Still in need of help.